# Post Object Filter by Custom Field, not title (ACF)

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

So I am using post object which allows me to search a custom post type by the title. What I want to do is search the custom post type by a custom field and have the custom field values returned. At the moment I have the following code in my functions.php file:-

```
function my_post_object_query( $args, $field, $post_id ) {

    // Get the search text
    $the_search = $args['s'];

    // Remove it so ACF won't search the posts based on title
    unset($args['s']);

    // Search based on custom field
    $args['meta_key'] = 'short_title';
    $args['meta_value'] =  $the_search;
    $args['meta_compare'] = 'LIKE';

    // return
    return $args;

}

// filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/name=product', 'my_post_object_query', 10, 3);
```

This is allowing me to search using a custom field but the returned values are still the the_title(). How can I change the returned values to the same custom field; short_title

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another filter for the post_object: `acf/fields/post_object/result`, that lets you customise the result (text) displayed for each option in the post object field.

Try something like this:

```
function my_post_object_result( $title, $post, $field, $post_id ) {

    /* Get whatever value you want here e.g. */
    $short_title= get_field('short_title', $post->ID);

    /* do any other processing you might want to do before returning it... */ 

    return $short_title;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/result/name=product', 'my_post_object_result', 10, 4);
```

**Reference**: [ACF Documentation for acf/fields/post_object/result](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-result/)

Comment: Perfect thank you! Although you've missed the $, so it's `return $short_title;`

Comment: Oops! I'll fix that typo, just in case anyone else might find this answer useful :)